# Declare a ThreadLocal dictionary

Tags: c#-4.0

I need to declare a dictionary that is global within a class, but the code using the dictionary will run as a thread, so I need to use ThreadLocal.   How do I declare that?

```
ThreadLocal<IDictionary<string, MyClass>>  is not correct.
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
private ThreadLocal<IDictionary<string, MyClass>> myDictionary;
```

Note that ThreadLocal only exists on .NET 4 (which I assume you're running considering the C# 4.0 tag), on lower .NET versions there is the [[ThreadStatic] attribute](http://theburningmonk.com/2010/10/threadstatic-vs-threadlocal/) with it's initialization quirks instead.